# How to convert a list of tensorflow EagerTensors to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have data that looks this when I print it:

```
data = [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.0034351824>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0003163157>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.00060091465>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0012879161>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0002799925>]
```

So this is a list where the elements are of type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`.

I would like to convert it to a standard numpy array. So in this case it would look like:

```
 array([-0.0034351824, 0.0003163157, 0.00060091465, 0.0012879161, 0.0002799925])
```

How can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.ravel` since you want a 1D list:

```
np.ravel(data)
```

```
array([0.22184575, 0.3621379 , 0.5509906 , 0.20388651, 0.94017696], dtype=float32)
```

Full example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = [tf.random.uniform((1,)) for i in range(5)]

np.ravel(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.